# How to transform elements of list into dict/tuple? Python

Tags: python

I need to transform this list:

```
[124, '-9.6713520', '-35.745578', 132, '-9.6713765', '-35.745620', 140, '-9.6712351', '-35.745561', 159, '-9.6712457', '-35.745545']
```

Into:

```
[{'uc': 124, 'location': (-9.6713520, -35.745578)}, 
{'uc': 132, 'location': (-9.6713765, -35.745620)},
{'uc': 140, 'location': (-9.6712351, -35.745561)},
{'uc': 159, 'location': (-9.6712457, -35.745545)}]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make an iterator from your list, you can zip it with itself three times to iterate in triples:

```
l = [124, '-9.6713520', '-35.745578', 132, '-9.6713765', '-35.745620', 140, '-9.6712351', '-35.745561', 159, '-9.6712457', '-35.745545']

it = iter(l)   
[{'uc': k, 'location': (float(a), float(b))} for k, a, b in zip(it, it, it)]
```

Giving you:

```
[{'uc': 124, 'location': (-9.671352, -35.745578)},
 {'uc': 132, 'location': (-9.6713765, -35.74562)},
 {'uc': 140, 'location': (-9.6712351, -35.745561)},
 {'uc': 159, 'location': (-9.6712457, -35.745545)}]
```

Comment: It seems unnecessarily obfuscated, `for k, a, b in zip(it, it, it)` would iterate the same way.

Comment: Thanks @wim — you're right. originally had a `*t` and didn't edit all the way. Fixed

Comment: The original poster clearly wanted the coordinates to be `float`s, not `str`s, you didn't do the conversion here.

Comment: Ugh, Thanks @Thyebri — I clearly need to avoid SO at the end of a long day...

Comment: [More fun variation](https://tio.run/##TY5BCoMwEEX3OcXsYqAVYzJGCz2JuBBpaMCaIHHRlp49TSxWZ/PnMY/PuKe/20nUbg5hhCu0vJQnoOcmrxQXWBY0kcBcSURVR@Ki3AVV4UGoVp3L4i@UAvmxoUrEsdkFieooSKQdIcbHV4y/zdnIAIDoxI/eZXq0vT/FEyNuNpPP2jddBnqBZYglox16b@wUeVs/BH6j7bxK2wHMBC/jMhPrUuqY2jPWsRC@).

Comment: Neat @KellyBundy That's nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a simple `for` loop and go through every 3 items in the list:

```
orig = [124, '-9.6713520', '-35.745578', 132, '-9.6713765', '-35.745620', 140, '-9.6712351', '-35.745561', 159, '-9.6712457', '-35.745545']
final = []
for i in range(0, len(orig), 3): # Note the 3 as that is the step
    new = {}
    new["uc"] = orig[i]
    new["location"] = (orig[i + 1], orig[i + 2])
    final.append(new)
print(final)
```

Outputs:

> [{'uc': 124, 'location': ('-9.6713520', '-35.745578')}, {'uc': 132, 'location': ('-9.6713765', '-35.745620')}, {'uc': 140, 'location': ('-9.6712351', '-35.745561')}, {'uc': 159, 'location': ('-9.6712457', '-35.745545')}]

or using list comprehension:

```
[{"uc": orig[i], "location": (orig[i + 1], orig[i + 2])} for i in range(0, len(orig), 3)]
```

Comment: Wrap the coordinates in `float()` as per OP's specification.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to append data dictionaries into a new list and this could be done by looping in the list you got and since you want new addition multiples of three, we can write the loop to jump each time 3 indexes and then your addition to the new list would be happening by only one line of code.

```
my_list = [124, '-9.6713520', '-35.745578', 132, '-9.6713765', '-35.745620', 140, '-9.6712351', '-35.745561', 159, '-9.6712457', '-35.745545']
new_list = []
steps = 3

for i in range(0, len(my_list), steps):
  new_list.append({'uc': my_list[i], 'location': (my_list[i+1], my_list[i+2])})

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

More variations using an iterator like Mark, but also using a `map` to float ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDBboMwDIbvPIVvJFJWNUCgnbQnQT0gFrRogUTBTOqmPTtz6NoitEOXS/jtD/sDf8Y3N@QHH@bZwgvUMisEpE/HXVnJXGX7NKZc7apCqepASebZHahKtQLKBZfF/gZkuZLrCWVMUh3vQKGqNVCo9JQkBknFoA7McgBIupj7xrPOugYFtXgS9DjZWK@/0qlNn2FqaY51bYPGDZSvj98J3E7nwsJde2AG@DSeGRoa747uDjknBx/MgOyyhT@m9K7PI1WjzlplpfpqWmRxUUQFfDR20iPnG8NL@XG3Lrh@cUPnLL3XexcQgva6wf/9S2tGZLEZRcWC0WrxO4vV2087cfGnI52N5Tz/AA)):

```
it = iter(l)   
ft = map(float, it)
result = [{'uc': uc, 'location': location}
          for uc, location in zip(it, zip(ft, ft))]
```

```
it = iter(l)   
ft = map(float, it)
keys = 'uc', 'location'
result = [dict(zip(keys, values))
          for values in zip(it, zip(ft, ft))]
```

```
from itertools import repeat
it = iter(l)   
ft = map(float, it)
result = list(map(dict, map(zip, repeat(['uc', 'location']), zip(it, zip(ft, ft)))))
```